# GA4 - views keep changing for a set range of dates

Tags: view, google-analytics-4, mobile-website

I created a report in which I can look at views on my website. When I look as an exemple at September 1st to September 30th, the number of views have changed since the last time I checked (in October). At first I thought it was because GA4 was new but it keeps doing that. Any idea why ?

I tried to look at other months to make sure that it was not just a month or just during the time of the transition to GA4.

Answer (score 0):

My first thought is to take a look at the sampling icon in the upper right hand corner. I don't know the in's and out's of their sampling techniques, but this could be a factor if \your report is being sampled at different rates, depending on when you view it.